# "Plurality" tag should not be a synonym of the "plural" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

- "Plural" would be for only for plural forms.
- "Plurality" works well for questions about when the use the singular and when to use the plural.

In some ways it's closer to [grammatical-number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-number) but that term is usually used more for agreement and pronouns than for singular vs plural in nouns.

Comment: Just a quick comment: this is not how it worked in practice. In practice, *every* question that was tagged with [plural] boiled down to either "should I use plural here" or "why is plural being used here". Consequently, *every* question that was tagged with [plural] was *also* tagged with [singular], and vice versa. (In other words, we have tons of questions falling into your second category, but barely a single one falling into the first.) The tag synonyms were not there from day one; they only got introduced after collecting months worth of data on how people actually use these tags.

Comment: @RegDwight: Hmm I guess all new SEs go through such stages until the tag excerpts get better and there are more users to correct badly tagged questions and more users have a feeling for how the tags work on a site.

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same thing, but they could be used as synonyms, cause they're similar, to make searching easier.

Comment: Hmm I guess when the sites are small general tags can help searching in some ways but as they grow more specific tags work better. Of course you can always have general and specific tags on the the same site as long as they are well-defined.

Comment: @hippietrail, and as long as there are lots of synonyms to help ease searching.